# How to create href in xsl using javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I am using below code to create href

```
<xsl:template name="pageHeader">
    <h1><xsl:value-of select="$TITLE"/></h1>
    <table width="100%">
    <tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right">Designed for use with <a <xsl:attribute name="href">javascript:returnHyperlink();</xsl:attribute> >JUnit</a> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <hr size="1"/>
</xsl:template>
```

```
</script>
       <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"><![CDATA[

        function returnHyperlink ()
        {
        var scrt_var =cur['env.PBCS_VERSION']; 
        return scrt_var;
        }
      ]]>
      </script>
```

Someone kindly correct me what is wrong in the code

Answer (score 0):

Your XSL code is not even well formed.

Use this code to create attribute:

```
<a><xsl:attribute name="href">javascript:returnHyperlink();</xsl:attribute>JUnit</a>
```

Or Like:

```
<a href="javascript:returnHyperlink();">JUnit</a>
```